# Constructing object on shared memory with integer identifier

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-interprocess

When I look at the samples of boost interprocess library, the objects are always constructed with string name.

```
segment.construct<Equipments>("name")("param1", "param2");
```

Is it possible to construct the object with integer identifier like

```
segment.construct<Equipments>(123)("param1", "param2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? In any case, you can do it in a "bit" dirty way:

```
segment.construct<Equipments>((char*)123)("param1", "param2");
```

As long as sizeof(char*) >= sizeof(int) on your platform (which it is on Win32/Win64), the pointer can be safely cast back to the integer without loss of information. Just be sure that you don't use the pointer value as a valid `char*` pointer.

**Oh, and you have to be sure that the underlying library code will not try to use the value as a valid char pointer.**

Comment: Thanks, it works. Actually I don't want to store my objects with string identifier. I wondered if I can sore them with integer identifiers.

Comment: I also tried char x = 123;  boost::interprocess::detail::char_ptr_holder<char> t(&x); segment.construct<Equipments>(t)... It works for chat but not integer type.

Comment: Well, `char` is just an integer with a very limited range (usually -128..127 signed, 0..255 unsigned).  So that too will work as long as your ID is not too large.